# Buiding kernel for an ARM processor

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, odroid

I working on Odroid XU3 with the ubuntu platform. For the DS5 software to crosscompile for profiling , I need to build Linux kernel with specific configuration. I am new to this stuff, but I have created the UImage of the kernel on the host machine for the Arm processor. I need to ask how one can get that kernel copy in the target platform i.e. Odroid.

Because for the profiling I need to have gatord and kernel with specific configuration installed on the target machine. I am done with gatord and build the kernel on host. Just need to copy it on target. But it is not happening using the sdcard of the odroid. Please let me know.

Comment: How do you have your SD card set up? ISTR when I was doing kernel work with an original Odroid-XU some time ago I had an SD card flashed with a pre-built image (either an Ubuntu one from the Odroid forums or the Arch Linux one, I forget which I settled on) which had separate boot and root partitions, and just overwrote the zImage in /boot.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have created uImage that seems like you have U-Boot as a bootloader on your target board. U-Boot in its turns can download kernel uImages via TFTP. I haven't worked with such devices as yours, but if it has Ethernet port, you could use it.
Also you have to know the U-Boot commands (fortunatelly there are a lot of information can be found over Internet, just ask google.)

Comment: I have created a UImage on ubuntu based host machine, not i have to copy that in target machine most probably using sd card. I am new to this stuff so i don't know much about it.
 I guess from the following link you will understand what I have done and what i need to do now --> [http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0482o/ric1362174541050.html]